# Cucumber Step definition failing

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, cucumber

I have a step definition that is failing.

From the feature below i have it failing at 'And that feature has a issue' (undefined local variable at title)

```
Feature: Viewing issue
In order to view the issues for a feature
As a user
I want to see them on that feature's page
Background:    
    Given there is a release called "Confluence"
    And that release has a feature:
      | title                | description   |
      | Make it shiny!       | Gradients! Starbursts! Oh my! |
    And that feature has a issue:
      | title                | description   |
      | First Issue          | This is a first issue. |
    And I am on the homepage

  Scenario: Viewing issue for a given feature
    When I follow "Confluence"
    Then I should see "Standards compliance"
    When I follow "Standards compliance"
    Then I should see "First Issue" 
    And I should see "This is a first issue."
```

How do i write a step definition for it guys.

this is what i have for the features definition and it works great but i've tried doing the same for issues objects and it doesn't work

```
Given /^that release has a feature:$/ do |table|
  table.hashes.each do |attributes|
    @release.features.create!(attributes)
  end
end
```

Comment: You need to post your code for the "And that feature has a issue' step definition.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use instance variables in your steps, as a best practice. It makes them dependent on each other.

I'd write your steps like this (in psuedo-ish code):

```
Given there is a release called <name>
    # create model

Given release <name> has a feature <table>
    release = Release.find_by_name(<name>)
    # rest of your code here is fine, but reference 'release' instead of '@release'

Given release <name>'s <feature_name> has issues <table>
    release = Release.find_by_name(<name>)
    feature = release.features.find_by_name(<feature_name>)
    table.hashes.each do |attributes|
       # create issue
    end
```

Then your Cucumber feature would read better like this:

```
Given there is a release called "Confluence"
And release "Confluence" has a feature:
  | title                | description   |
  | Make it shiny!       | Gradients! Starbursts! Oh my! |
And release "Confluence"'s "Make it shiny!" feature has issues
  | title                | description   |
  | First Issue          | This is a first issue. |
```